# How do I read Safari's cache.db through Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite, caching, safari

**What I Want**

I want to read the cache of Safari through Active Record. Essentially, I want to [peek inside the cache like this](http://sindro.me/2008/1/20/extracting-data-from-apple-safari-s-cache) except from within a Rails app.

**What I've Tried**

I copied the Cache.db file 
I set up the environment.rb file in a new Rails app with the path of a copy of the Safari Cache.db SQLite Database.
Ran db:migrate

This seems to generate a schema, but I'm not sure how I read this data now. The schema also has an error:

```
# Could not dump table "cfurl_cache_response" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'time_stamp'
```

I think I'm going down the wrong road here.

**Requirements**

- I don't want to write any data, just read it.
- I want to read the URL and HTML of pages stored in the cache.
- Something dead simple - I'm a Rails newbie.
- Quick to implement - this is for a quick and dirty prototype.

**What's the Best Approach?**

Should I be connecting to the Safari cache through a second SQLite database where I can construct a read only query of the data? Then somehow read this in turn through my Rails app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to read from it, your might as well just use the sqlite3 gem http://sqlite-ruby.rubyforge.org/:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Then in ruby:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sqlite3'

db = SQLite3::Database.new('/Users/Andrew/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari')
```

Then you can read it using normal sql:

```
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM cfurl_cache_response'
```

Comment: Talk about the simplest possible thing that will work. This is perfect - just what I was after. Thankyou!